# Django Rest Browsable API available at different url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

Is there any way to access Django Rest user interface in different address than api url itself? E.g somwhere in Django admin ( exampleUrl.com/admin.api )

I've tried to extend admin template by:

adding url
`path('admin/api/', views.index),`

creating view:

`from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'admin/rest_api.html')`

and adding this line templates/admin/rest_api.html

`{% extends 'rest_framework/base.html' %}`

but it returned following error:
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'`

`Error during template rendering
In template /home/adam/apps/WB/heartbeat/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/base.html, error at line 160`

Line 160:
`<pre class="prettyprint"><span class="meta nocode"><b>HTTP {{ response.status_code }} {{ response.status_text }}</b>{% autoescape off %}{% for key, val in response_headers|items %}`

Any idea how to solve this (in some other way maybe)?

Comment: I don't think the error is related to the above code. Can some more code be shared?

Comment: @MonishKNair I've edited question

Comment: In your view you don't pass an items list (maybe some queryset)

Comment: @Adam Share some more code or error info

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis how do i pass item list to with 'extends' ? And what should It be then? I can't see any data passed in rest_frameworks views

Comment: What is your models ?